# How can I access a user's ID from default.ctp?

Tags: cakephp

Once a user is logged in, they are able to use the profile button, which should redirect them to their profile. However, I cannot get default.ctp to access the current user. I think this is the closest I've gotten:

```
<?php if($loggedIn) : ?>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Search', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search']); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Profile', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User.Id')]); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Settings', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'settings']); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Logout', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout']); ?></li>
<?php else : ?>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Register', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register']); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Login', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login']); ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In view.ctp from UsersController user_id is accessed as $user->user_id because it is declared as such:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Profiles']
]);
$this->set('user', $user);
```

I've tried using similar code in AppController with beforeRender and beforeFilter but nothing seems to work. I feel like I'm super close and have probably just been using the wrong combination of things. Fairly new to CakePHP (3.8) so any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spent way more time than I needed to on this, but as soon as I posted the question my next attempt solved it.

in AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $user = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User');
    if(!empty($user)) {
       $this->set('user', $user); 
    }        
}
```

in default.ctp:

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Search', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search', $user['user_id']]); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Profile', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $user['user_id']]); ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link('Settings', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'settings', $user['user_id']]); ?></li>
```

in UsersController:

```
    public function profile($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Profiles']
    ]);
    $this->set('user', $user);
}

public function search($id = null) 
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Profiles']
    ]);
    $this->set('user', $user);
}

public function settings($id = null) 
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Profiles']
    ]);
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In view.ctp access all user data:

```
$user = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User');
```

then

```
echo $user['id'];
```

or

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id');
```

If you need auth user data in controller:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth');
$user = $this->Auth->user();
```